# VS2017 Debug: no Launch URL setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-express

Project (full net461, core 1.1) converted from VS2015:

[image]

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:17901/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also no browsers opens automatically after F5. (But site opens when I go to url manually).

And I also cannot create not Core web project in 2017 to see how it works - VS just writes something about "failed to create project" in bottom line and empty solution explorer, only folder created, nothing in Output, nothing in `devenv /Log C:/log.xml` log.

Comment: Try closing VS2017 and deleting the .vs folder in your solution root folder

Comment: Did not help.``

Answer (score 1):

To fix: enable "Azure App service Tools"